# Conditionally delete Node of HTML by JS

Tags: jquery, html, nodes

Trying to delete specific HTML Node of specific div. Delete all `.widget-content li.lists` if there more then one `li.lists` (*there will be mane list item*), but don't want to delete first child `li.lists:first-child`, means keep first-child.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper delete">

<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li class="lists"> 
    Content First
</li>
<li class="lists"> <!-- Delete this-->
    Content second
</li>
<li class="lists"> <!-- Delete this-->
    Content third
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.widget-content li').not(':first-child').remove();
```

I have used this jQuery, but I want to do this conditionally by if statement. Mean if there have more then one `li:lists` then delete all `li:lists` with out first list `li.lists:first-child`.

**Note**: want to this by If statement.

JS Fiddle

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qwc6h1y2/3/)

Comment: But seriously ... why?

Comment: Because my question is for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var numItems = $(".widget-content li").length; //or whatever class/id you want to count
   if (numItems > 1){
       $('.widget-content li').not(':first-child').remove();
   }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwc6h1y2/7/

Comment: Thanks, this the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('.widget-content ul li').first().siblings().remove();
```

or

```
$('.lists').first().siblings().remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i question for If statement, means want to do this by If statement only.